# how to spark-submit job to spark cluster on local kubernetes created by minikube

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

I am reading the [blog](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/scaling-spark-with-kubernetes-part-6/) and tried to run the [codes](https://github.com/phatak-dev/kubernetes-spark).

```
$kubectl get po
NAME                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
spark-master-668325562-w369p    1/1       Running   0          23s
spark-worker-1868749523-xt7hg   1/1       Running   0          23s
```

Now, the spark cluster is running well on local kubernetes cluster created by minikube. I am trying to submit spark job to it by the following command:

```
spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin$ ./spark-submit --master spark://<spark-master>:7077 /home/me/workspace/myproj/myproj.jar
```

How to know the spark-master IP? I just followed the above steps to do it and cannot find related tutorials about how to **know/set** the spark-master IP.

Anyone can explain it? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried the following ips, but failed.

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.42.55

$kubectl get svc 
NAME           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
kubernetes     10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP             3h
spark-master   10.0.0.175   <none>        8080/TCP,7077/TCP   42m
```

Error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:524)
    at NetworkScanCounter$.main(network-scan-counter.scala:68)
    at NetworkScanCounter.main(network-scan-counter.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kubectl get po -o wide` will show the pod ip address, you need expose using Nodeport, after that you can reach master using minikueip:service port.

Answer (score 0):

The latest apache spark 2.3.0 supports kubernetes .

`$ spark-submit --master k8s://https://127.0.0.1:8443 --name cfe8  --deploy-mode cluster --class com.yyy.Application --conf spark.executor.instances=4 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=anantpukale/spark_app:1.2 local://CashFlow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar`

Points to be noted

1.As of now spark 2.3.0 supports only cluster mode of deployment.

2.application jar has to be in either HDFS or docker-image or any remote location accessible through http. In above command local keyword indicates that local to docker container.

3.The ip and port passed in master is found in

`$ kubectl cluster-info`

Once see the trigger above command, you can see pod and service been created on kubernetes dashboard.

[Reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html)